# directing Ubuntu install to correct device

Tags: dual-boot, devices

Sorry to ask what must be an oft-asked question but I am not seeing another thread with the solution.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 for a dual boot setup on a system that has two HDDs on it, one 149Gb the other 249Gb .

[image]

[image]

Windows 7 is already installed on the 149Gb drive.
When I just run the Ubuntu installation from USB, it defaults to the 249Gb drive. 
WHen I restart, my system goes straight into Windows 7, no Dual Boot option on startup.

From my reading I think I need to push the Ubuntu install to the same device as Windows now occupies. I started down the last option in the Install (something along the lines of "manually install by specifying partitions") but that leads me to a partitioning type screen that I don't feel like messing with.
can someone advise or direct me to the step by step instructions I need.

Or, does this problem have nothing to do with the fact that I have two physical HDDs with one OS on each?

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not install Ubuntu on the same partition as Windows**, that will overwrite your Windows installation and loose all your data. As for images, you need a bit more [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to attach images, just upload them to a service like http://imgur.com and [edit] your post to include the links. Another user will add them to your post for you.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like you did not install a boot loader (which gives you a choice of which OS to boot), follow the procedure here: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432)

Answer (score 0):

IN the end I just took the inelegant approach of disconnecting the 2nd HDD, and redoing the Ubuntu installation on the sole primary drive. This time it prompted me as described in the install steps to allocate space between Windows and Ubuntu.
I reconnected the 2nd drive and on reboot, I got the Dual Boot prompt choices.
There must be a more elegant approach but this got the job done.

Peter